# How to automatically initizlize the 'dispatcherServlet' the moment after the web app started in the spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, hystrix, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I am working on feign client with hystrix in a spring boot application. I started a eureka server and register two providers. In the feign client application I added the hystrix support. And when I request the service first time, I got the hystrix result, but after that every request could get the expected result from the provider. From the log, I see that the `dispatcherServlet` was lazily initialized after the first requested was made, not after the web app started. And this extends the timeout span of the hystrix. In this case, I always get the false result on the first request because of the lazy initialization of `dispatcherServlet`.

1. How could I get the first request correctly?
2. Is it ok to initialize
   the `dispatcherServet` the moment after the web starts? If so,
   how can I do it?

log:

```
:: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.0.RELEASE)

2016-10-13 15:06:03.677  INFO 41459 --- [           main] c.i.c.s.MovieFeignHystrixApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-10-13 15:06:03.723  INFO 41459 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2e6a5539: startup date [Thu Oct 13 15:06:03 CST 2016]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6e509ffa
2016-10-13 15:06:05.005  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'hystrixFeature' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCircuitBreakerConfiguration$HystrixWebConfiguration; factoryMethodName=hystrixFeature; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCircuitBreakerConfiguration$HystrixWebConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCircuitBreakerConfiguration; factoryMethodName=hystrixFeature; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCircuitBreakerConfiguration.class]]
2016-10-13 15:06:05.431  WARN 41459 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  : Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'refreshScope' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
2016-10-13 15:06:05.705  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=cc11fab8-4eec-3228-9e14-ac8a7dca16b2
2016-10-13 15:06:05.730  INFO 41459 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2016-10-13 15:06:06.367  INFO 41459 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$76aeae65] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-10-13 15:06:07.056  INFO 41459 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8022 (http)
2016-10-13 15:06:07.078  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-10-13 15:06:07.079  INFO 41459 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.4
2016-10-13 15:06:07.266  INFO 41459 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-10-13 15:06:07.267  INFO 41459 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3544 ms
2016-10-13 15:06:07.883  INFO 41459 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-10-13 15:06:07.902  INFO 41459 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'metricFilter' to: [/*]
2016-10-13 15:06:07.903  INFO 41459 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-10-13 15:06:07.903  INFO 41459 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-10-13 15:06:07.903  INFO 41459 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-10-13 15:06:07.903  INFO 41459 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-10-13 15:06:07.903  INFO 41459 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-10-13 15:06:07.904  INFO 41459 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
2016-10-13 15:06:08.071  INFO 41459 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@140d1230: startup date [Thu Oct 13 15:06:08 CST 2016]; parent: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2e6a5539
2016-10-13 15:06:08.111  INFO 41459 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2016-10-13 15:06:09.841  WARN 41459 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2016-10-13 15:06:09.842  INFO 41459 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2016-10-13 15:06:09.857  INFO 41459 --- [           main] c.netflix.config.DynamicPropertyFactory  : DynamicPropertyFactory is initialized with configuration sources: com.netflix.config.ConcurrentCompositeConfiguration@631cb129
2016-10-13 15:06:10.026  INFO 41459 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2e6a5539: startup date [Thu Oct 13 15:06:03 CST 2016]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6e509ffa
2016-10-13 15:06:10.240  INFO 41459 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/feign/{id}],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.itmuch.cloud.study.user.entity.User com.itmuch.cloud.study.user.controller.FeignHystrixController.findByIdFeign(java.lang.Long)
2016-10-13 15:06:10.244  INFO 41459 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-10-13 15:06:10.245  INFO 41459 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-10-13 15:06:10.383  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-10-13 15:06:10.383  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-10-13 15:06:10.468  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-10-13 15:06:11.460  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EnvironmentMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2016-10-13 15:06:11.461  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env || /env.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-10-13 15:06:11.462  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/hystrix.stream/**]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.cloud.netflix.endpoint.ServletWrappingEndpoint.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception
2016-10-13 15:06:11.464  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/beans || /beans.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-10-13 15:06:11.467  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/configprops || /configprops.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-10-13 15:06:11.467  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/refresh || /refresh.json],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.GenericPostableMvcEndpoint.invoke()
2016-10-13 15:06:11.468  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/resume || /resume.json],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.GenericPostableMvcEndpoint.invoke()
2016-10-13 15:06:11.470  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/pause || /pause.json],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.GenericPostableMvcEndpoint.invoke()
2016-10-13 15:06:11.471  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/autoconfig || /autoconfig.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-10-13 15:06:11.474  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/heapdump || /heapdump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/octet-stream]}" onto public void org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HeapdumpMvcEndpoint.invoke(boolean,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException,javax.servlet.ServletException
2016-10-13 15:06:11.475  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/health || /health.json],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(java.security.Principal)
2016-10-13 15:06:11.476  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/info || /info.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-10-13 15:06:11.479  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/restart || /restart.json],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.context.restart.RestartMvcEndpoint.invoke()
2016-10-13 15:06:11.480  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2016-10-13 15:06:11.480  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics || /metrics.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-10-13 15:06:11.506  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/dump || /dump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-10-13 15:06:11.529  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/archaius || /archaius.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-10-13 15:06:11.562  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/trace || /trace.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-10-13 15:06:11.563  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentManagerMvcEndpoint.value(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2016-10-13 15:06:11.566  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env/reset],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object> org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentManagerMvcEndpoint.reset()
2016-10-13 15:06:11.580  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/features || /features.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-10-13 15:06:11.581  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/mappings || /mappings.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-10-13 15:06:11.911  WARN 41459 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2016-10-13 15:06:11.911  INFO 41459 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2016-10-13 15:06:12.096  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-10-13 15:06:12.118  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'refreshScope' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2016-10-13 15:06:12.122  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'environmentManager' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2016-10-13 15:06:12.129  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'configurationPropertiesRebinder' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2016-10-13 15:06:12.132  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'refreshEndpoint' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2016-10-13 15:06:12.134  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'restartEndpoint' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2016-10-13 15:06:12.139  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'environmentManager': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager]
2016-10-13 15:06:12.373  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'restartEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.restart:name=restartEndpoint,type=RestartEndpoint]
2016-10-13 15:06:12.394  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'refreshScope': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh:name=refreshScope,type=RefreshScope]
2016-10-13 15:06:12.412  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinder': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties:name=configurationPropertiesRebinder,context=2e6a5539,type=ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder]
2016-10-13 15:06:12.427  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'refreshEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.endpoint:name=refreshEndpoint,type=RefreshEndpoint]
2016-10-13 15:06:12.720  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2016-10-13 15:06:12.741  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory       : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
2016-10-13 15:06:13.225  INFO 41459 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2016-10-13 15:06:13.228  INFO 41459 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2016-10-13 15:06:13.462  INFO 41459 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2016-10-13 15:06:13.462  INFO 41459 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2016-10-13 15:06:13.838  INFO 41459 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2016-10-13 15:06:13.892  INFO 41459 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
2016-10-13 15:06:13.892  INFO 41459 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
2016-10-13 15:06:13.892  INFO 41459 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
2016-10-13 15:06:13.892  INFO 41459 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
2016-10-13 15:06:13.892  INFO 41459 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
2016-10-13 15:06:13.893  INFO 41459 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: true
2016-10-13 15:06:13.893  INFO 41459 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2016-10-13 15:06:14.350  INFO 41459 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : The response status is 200
2016-10-13 15:06:14.353  INFO 41459 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Starting heartbeat executor: renew interval is: 30
2016-10-13 15:06:14.356  INFO 41459 --- [           main] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : InstanceInfoReplicator onDemand update allowed rate per min is 4
2016-10-13 15:06:14.362  INFO 41459 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1476342374362 with initial instances count: 3
2016-10-13 15:06:14.477  INFO 41459 --- [           main] c.n.e.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration : Registering application microservice-consumer-movie-feign-with-hystrix-stream with eureka with status UP
2016-10-13 15:06:14.478  INFO 41459 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1476342374477, current=UP, previous=STARTING]
2016-10-13 15:06:14.479  INFO 41459 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_MICROSERVICE-CONSUMER-MOVIE-FEIGN-WITH-HYSTRIX-STREAM/10.106.192.57:microservice-consumer-movie-feign-with-hystrix-stream:8022: registering service...
2016-10-13 15:06:14.542  INFO 41459 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_MICROSERVICE-CONSUMER-MOVIE-FEIGN-WITH-HYSTRIX-STREAM/10.106.192.57:microservice-consumer-movie-feign-with-hystrix-stream:8022 - registration status: 204
2016-10-13 15:06:14.548  INFO 41459 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2016-10-13 15:06:14.555  INFO 41459 --- [           main] ration$HystrixMetricsPollerConfiguration : Starting poller
2016-10-13 15:06:14.661  INFO 41459 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8022 (http)
2016-10-13 15:06:14.662  INFO 41459 --- [           main] c.n.e.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration : Updating port to 8022
2016-10-13 15:06:14.668  INFO 41459 --- [           main] c.i.c.s.MovieFeignHystrixApplication     : Started MovieFeignHystrixApplication in 14.338 seconds (JVM running for 15.302)










2016-10-13 15:06:59.127  INFO 41459 --- [nio-8022-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-10-13 15:06:59.128  INFO 41459 --- [nio-8022-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-10-13 15:06:59.202  INFO 41459 --- [nio-8022-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 74 ms
2016-10-13 15:07:00.304  INFO 41459 --- [provider-user-1] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@353c426d: startup date [Thu Oct 13 15:07:00 CST 2016]; parent: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2e6a5539
2016-10-13 15:07:00.407  INFO 41459 --- [provider-user-1] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2016-10-13 15:07:00.827  INFO 41459 --- [provider-user-1] c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Flipping property: microservice-provider-user.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
2016-10-13 15:07:00.882  INFO 41459 --- [provider-user-1] c.n.u.concurrent.ShutdownEnabledTimer    : Shutdown hook installed for: NFLoadBalancer-PingTimer-microservice-provider-user
2016-10-13 15:07:00.944  INFO 41459 --- [provider-user-1] c.netflix.loadbalancer.BaseLoadBalancer  : Client:microservice-provider-user instantiated a LoadBalancer:DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=microservice-provider-user,current list of Servers=[],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {},Server stats: []}ServerList:null
2016-10-13 15:07:00.953  INFO 41459 --- [provider-user-1] c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : Using serverListUpdater PollingServerListUpdater
2016-10-13 15:07:00.993  INFO 41459 --- [provider-user-1] c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Flipping property: microservice-provider-user.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
2016-10-13 15:07:00.996  INFO 41459 --- [provider-user-1] c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : DynamicServerListLoadBalancer for client microservice-provider-user initialized: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=microservice-provider-user,current list of Servers=[10.106.192.57:8001, 10.106.192.57:8000],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {defaultzone=[Zone:defaultzone;    Instance count:2;   Active connections count: 0;    Circuit breaker tripped count: 0;   Active connections per server: 0.0;]
},Server stats: [[Server:10.106.192.57:8001;    Zone:defaultZone;   Total Requests:0;   Successive connection failure:0;    Total blackout seconds:0;   Last connection made:Thu Jan 01 08:00:00 CST 1970;  First connection made: Thu Jan 01 08:00:00 CST 1970;    Active Connections:0;   total failure count in last (1000) msecs:0; average resp time:0.0;  90 percentile resp time:0.0;    95 percentile resp time:0.0;    min resp time:0.0;  max resp time:0.0;  stddev resp time:0.0]
, [Server:10.106.192.57:8000;   Zone:defaultZone;   Total Requests:0;   Successive connection failure:0;    Total blackout seconds:0;   Last connection made:Thu Jan 01 08:00:00 CST 1970;  First connection made: Thu Jan 01 08:00:00 CST 1970;    Active Connections:0;   total failure count in last (1000) msecs:0; average resp time:0.0;  90 percentile resp time:0.0;    95 percentile resp time:0.0;    min resp time:0.0;  max resp time:0.0;  stddev resp time:0.0]
]}ServerList:org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.eureka.DomainExtractingServerList@14ee3ae0
2016-10-13 15:07:01.302  INFO 41459 --- [ HystrixTimer-1] FeignHystrixClient$HystrixClientFallback : 异常发生，进入fallback方法，接收的参数：id = 4
2009@@@@@@@@
2016-10-13 15:07:01.959  INFO 41459 --- [erListUpdater-0] c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Flipping property: microservice-provider-user.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
```

Thanks.

Comment: The servlet is already initialized by default, unless you have overridden the default servlet.

Comment: I didn't override the default servlet, not sure whether the servlet was overridden in the hystrix framework.

Answer (score 0):

I add this config `hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled=false`
 in the application.yml, and it worked. And there is a similar solution here.[Initial Request with Feign, Ribbon, Hystrix, and Consul Fails](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/768)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is add config: `spring.mvc.servlet.load-on-startup: 1`. But this time, it still could turn on the hystrix rule to return false result.